# How to empty a list in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to empty a list. How to do that?

Answer (score 307, accepted):

It's really easy:

```
myList.Clear();
```

Comment: ...if the list is actually a `List<>`, `ArrayList`, or implements `IList`. ;)

Comment: @Lucero does it be called as a list if it is neither of those?

Comment: Since this is a top hit in google and I run into this problem, I'm necro commenting this. If you use the same list in a loop and use clear, the list will often keep reference to old objects - I often end up using = new LisT<T>(); due to the fact that it clears all old allocations instantly. For most people though, .Clear(); will suffice, but if you find a list acting strangely - try using = new List<T>();.

Comment: I am going to double necrocomment this because some misinformation has been provided here as of 2020.`List<T>.Clear` properly clears all references which allows the GC to clear the allocs when necessary. `new List<T>` does NOT do this and is unsuitable in effectively all scenarios

Answer (score 30):

If by "list" you mean a `List<T>`, then the [Clear](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwb5h52a.aspx) method is what you want:

```
List<string> list = ...;
...
list.Clear();
```

You should get into the habit of searching the MSDN documentation on these things.

Here's how to quickly search for documentation on various bits of that type:

- [List Class](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=list+class) - provides the `List<T>` class itself (**this is where you should've started**)
- [List.Clear Method](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=list.clear+method) - provides documentation on the method Clear
- [List.Count Property](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=list.count+property) - provides documentation on the property Count

All of these Google queries lists a bundle of links, but typically you want the first one that google gives you in each case.

Comment: "All of these lists a bundle of links, but typically you want the first one." Unless you want to empty the list?

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more clear. You typically want the first link that Google gives you, not the "List Class".

Answer (score 18):

Option #1: Use [Clear()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwb5h52a(v=vs.110).aspx) function to empty the `List<T>` and retain it's capacity.

- > Count is set to 0, and references to other objects from elements of
  >   the collection are also released.
- > Capacity remains unchanged.

Option #2 - Use [Clear()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwb5h52a(v=vs.110).aspx) and [TrimExcess()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132207(v=vs.110).aspx) functions to set `List<T>` to initial state.

- > Count is set to 0, and references to other objects from elements of
  >   the collection are also released.
- > Trimming an empty `List<T>` sets the capacity of the List to the
  >   default capacity.

**Definitions**

[Count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3(v=vs.110).aspx) = number of elements that are actually in the `List<T>`

[Capacity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y52x03h2(v=vs.110).aspx) =  total number of elements the internal data structure can hold without resizing.

**Clear() Only**

```
List<string> dinosaurs = new List<string>();    
dinosaurs.Add("Compsognathus");
dinosaurs.Add("Amargasaurus");
dinosaurs.Add("Deinonychus");
Console.WriteLine("Count: {0}", dinosaurs.Count);
Console.WriteLine("Capacity: {0}", dinosaurs.Capacity);
dinosaurs.Clear();
Console.WriteLine("\nClear()");
Console.WriteLine("\nCount: {0}", dinosaurs.Count);
Console.WriteLine("Capacity: {0}", dinosaurs.Capacity);
```

**Clear() and TrimExcess()**

```
List<string> dinosaurs = new List<string>();
dinosaurs.Add("Triceratops");
dinosaurs.Add("Stegosaurus");
Console.WriteLine("Count: {0}", dinosaurs.Count);
Console.WriteLine("Capacity: {0}", dinosaurs.Capacity);
dinosaurs.Clear();
dinosaurs.TrimExcess();
Console.WriteLine("\nClear() and TrimExcess()");
Console.WriteLine("\nCount: {0}", dinosaurs.Count);
Console.WriteLine("Capacity: {0}", dinosaurs.Capacity);
```

Answer (score 13):

To give an alternative answer (Who needs 5 equal answers?):

```
list.Add(5); 
// list contains at least one element now
list = new List<int>();
// list in "list" is empty now
```

Keep in mind that all other references to the old list have not been cleared (depending on the situation, this might be what you want). Also, in terms of performance, it is usually a bit slower.

Comment: Can you verify that setting list = new List<>() is actually slower than list.Clear();? According to MSDN (link below) list.Clear(); is an O(N) operation, and I can't imagine instantiating a new list would take longer than  that.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwb5h52a(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: DotNetPerls did a benchmark and found that new List<> is faster. http://www.dotnetperls.com/list-clear

Comment: By extension, also be mindful that `list` has a new reference. So don't use that if you're using a lock on that list.

Comment: @GerhardPowell According to the article you provided, making a new List<> compared to using the `Clear()` method is not faster anymore. `In the results, calling Clear() on the List was faster.`

Comment: Clear() will manually clear the list (O(n)), new List<> will delete the reference to the old list and make GC clear the old one (obviously also O(n)). So instantiation of a new list seems faster until there is need for garbage collection - in which case, reusing the old list (with clearing) becomes more efficient.

Answer (score 6):

you can do that

```
var list = new List<string>();
list.Clear();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the clear method

```
List<string> test = new List<string>();
test.Clear();
```

Answer (score 4):

You need the Clear() function on the list, like so.

```
List<object> myList = new List<object>();

myList.Add(new object()); // Add something to the list

myList.Clear() // Our list is now empty
```